# Windows Location in hexadecimals?

Tags: windows, dos

I was going through the source code of a rainmeter skin and i could not understand :

```
TextShortcut1=Computer
TextShortcut2=Libraries
TextShortcut3=Internet
TextShortcut4=Media Player
TextShortcut5=Control Panel
TextShortcut6=Trash
TextShortcut7=ShutDown

TextPath1=::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
TextPath2=shell:Libraries
TextPath3=http://google.com
TextPath4=shell:MusicLibrary
TextPath5=::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002b30309d}
TextPath6=::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}
TextPath7=rundll32.exe user32.dll LockWorkStation
```

Can anyone tell me what

```
::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002b30309d}
::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}
```

these are

and also how can we get one of these for a specific location from our computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are CLSID (Windows Class Identifiers). Certain special folders within the operating system are identified by unique strings.

```
20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D is My Computer
21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002b30309d is Control Panel
645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E is Recycle Bin
```

Source:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/110919-clsid-key-list-windows-7-a.html

In response to the comment:

> can i have Class Identifiers for any folder on Computer or is it just
>   the bunch of those.

There isn't much reason for you to add more clsids, since you can just go to other locations by typing the normal path. This is a set list that is in the registry somewhere for special folders that don't really have "paths" like C:\windows does.

> what is "shell:Something" is it a cmd command or location

shell: is similar to above. It is a convenient way of accessing special folders. Here is a good site for a list: http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-shell-keyword.html . It is more of a shortcut for Windows Explorer to access a specific location than it is a command. You cant use them in batch files as far as I know (no command line stuff).

> what is %something% like %temp%

Those are environment variables. You can usually count on certain ones existing, but the user can change these. Here is a list of some more:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variables#Microsoft_Windows

> how do they all differ?

Well, basically, they are just different ways of accessing the same thing. Some things are more backwards compatible than others, so you have to make that choice when the time comes. If you know your app is going to be on Windows 7 and above, you can make use of some of the more convenient shell:something ones. But if it needs to run on Windows 2000, you might have to rely more on older stuff like environment variables. Environment variables can also be customized by the user.

Comment: can i have Class Identifiers for any folder on Computer or is it just the bunch of those. And also what is "shell:Something" is it a cmd command or location and please do tell what is %something% like %temp% means and how they all differ.

Comment: @Mayank I did my best to answer your questions. Let me know if there is anything that isn't clear.